# Socket exception : no such host known when connecting sql server to visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ssms

Hey guys I know this might seem like a duplicate but please here me out, I assure you I have been searching for hours on how to fix this issue. I have a sql server hosted here at the office, Im making a unity based application that I need to be able to get data in. I have it set-up in a test right now just to see if I can even reach the data.

Here is the code I use to open a connection with the server:

```
`using System.Data.SqlClient;`


>SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=tcp:(serverName),(assigned not defult port);Database='db name';Persist Security Info=(bool);User ID=*******;Password=*********");
( stars are filled in with appropriate info ) 
        con.Open();
```

I get the error :

> SocketException: No such host is known.
>
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName)
>   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion)
>   Rethrow as TdsInternalException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsComm..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds..ctor (System.String dataSource, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion tdsVersion)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds70..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout, TdsVersion version)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.Tds80..ctor (System.String server, Int32 port, Int32 packetSize, Int32 timeout)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPoolManager.CreateConnection (Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionInfo info)
>   Mono.Data.Tds.Protocol.TdsConnectionPool.GetConnection ()
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()
>   Rethrow as SqlException: Server does not exist or connection refused.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open ()
>   SQLConnect.Name () (at Assets/Scripts/SQLConnect.cs:27)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:154)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:637)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:773)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:52)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

Which occurs at the line `con.open();`

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I feel like its a connection string issue but I don't know the correct one to use, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for joining Stack Overflow! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the IP instead of hostname? Also, you may not need the `tcp:` prefix (I'd try with and without).

Comment: I have tried using the IP instead of port number so that cant be it , unfortunately @EBrown

Comment: @Zack And what error do you get when you try the IP? Saying "I have tried ... so that can't be it" is not helpful to yourself or anyone else - we need to know what went wrong in order to help you. Is the error the same? If not, what error is it?

Comment: @Zack Also, you say "IP instead of port number" which is not what I said, you should be using IP instead of *server name*, so `IP,port` instead.